# JBoss drools checking value of HashMap by passing a key

Tags: java, drools

Is there a way I can check the value of a HashMap in "when" block, by passing a key.

Something like(may not be the actual way)

```
rule "checkHM"
when
  $account : Account( hm.get("A") == "B") 
then
  System.out.println("HashMap has value B" );
end
```

Here Account is a class and hm is a HashMap in this class.
hm has key/value pair as "A"/"B".

I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work just like

```
rule "checkHM"
when
  $account : Account( hm[ "A" ] == "B" )
then
  System.out.println( "HashMap has value B" );
end
```

**P.S.** The reason why `get()` with HashMap might not work is probably due to the fact that Drools expects the facts to follow JavaBeans standard, and thus the method would need to be `getGet()` for it to work directly.

Comment: The original code works as posted, as does the alternative posted by @J Andy. (The remark about "get()" doesn't apply in this case. In fact, any expression returning a boolean should work in recent versions of Drools. - I just wonder why OP needs others to try this out for him.

Comment: On using   $account : Account( hm[ "A" ] == "B" ) got an error Exception in thread "main" org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Exception executing predicate hm["A"] == "C"
 at org.drools.rule.PredicateConstraint.isAllowed(PredicateConstraint.java:279)
 at org.drools.reteoo.AlphaNode.assertObject(AlphaNode.java:141)
 at org.drools.reteoo.SingleObjectSinkAdapter.propagateAssertObject(SingleObjectSinkAdapter.java:59)
 at org.drools.reteoo.ObjectTypeNode.assertObject(ObjectTypeNode.java:190)

Comment: Finally the code that worked is $map: HashMap(this["A"] == "B") after inserting hm into the ksession